# cakephp passing value from Htmlhelper Tag in view

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp

I have db derived Quantity variable and a rate field as form input. When the rate is entered,the quantity and rate value is passed to a function.My problem is that displaying Quantity as a text, I am unable to pass the value to the function. If i use FormHelper for quantity it is okay but i need to display it as text.
Is my approach and syntax correct? My main requirement is to display quantity as text and pass its value to the function.

My code is as below:

```
  <?php echo $this->Html->tag("quantity".$i,$b['Material']['quantity'], array("label" =>false,'size'=>'6','value'=>$b['Material']['quantity'],'id'=>'quantity_id'.$i));?>
</div>
```

Below is the js function called:

```
var quantity=$('#quantity_id'+k).val();
alert(quantity);
var rate=$('#rate_id'+k).val();
var tax=$('#tax_id'+k).val();
```

My problem is that the quantity value is not being passed to the function, alert displays an empty message.Please Help

Comment: Are you sure that the resulting HTML from php provides a `div#quantity_id` ? and the page is HTML-wellformed?

Comment: `tag` function expects first argument to be a valid HTML tag (`div`, `span` etc...). Probabily you want to use FormHelper and not HTMLHelper.

Comment: I need to display the quantity field which is a variable as a text. but the rate field as form input. If i make the quantity as form input, it works fine but i need to display the quantity as text not form input.